# how to infer type of a protobuf decoded message?

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers, protobufjs

I have this MessageType extracted from a .proto file:

```
export type MessageType = {

    template_id: number
}
```

The decode function shows:

[image]

> Maybe the protobuf library expects to extend with the above Object Type

`class Message<T extends object = object>`

Doing so it results in not finding the type.

```
import protobuf from 'protobufjs'
...
const { template_id }:protobuf.Message<MessageType> = decode(payload)
```

[image]

> Property 'template_id' does not exist on type 'Message'.ts(2339)

I tried fixing it by using `unknown` keyword, but this can't be the solution?

```
decode(payload) as unknown as MessageType
```